# Xamarin Forms Mediaplugin Fileprovider

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement the [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) but I am running into a problem. I have done all steps in the [setup instructions](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#important-permission-information) and get the following error:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/file_paths')
```

As explained in the [setup instructions](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#important-permission-information) - in my Android project, I have added a folder inside the Resources-folder, called xml - containing a file called file_paths.xml with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
<external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

I expect this problem to be related to either the above or the AndroidManifest.xml, so I'll include my complete AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.company.Kvitt" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="Kvitt.Android">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                  android:authorities="com.company.Kvitt.fileprovider"
                  android:exported="false"
                  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                       android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help or ideas on how to solve this error are really appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
The path is: Kvitt.Android\Resources\xml\file_paths.xml, this is correct - right?
After a build (does not succeed of course), there is no res-folder in Kvitt.Android/obj/Debug/android/

Comment: Thank you so much! It was due to the xml's build action not being AndroidResource. Not sure how I can accept your answer when it's in a comment.

Comment: I converted the comments to an answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `res/xml` directory should be in the same sub-folder as other Resources; drawable, layout, mipmap-XXX, etc...

- Do a clean all / build all just as a double check
- Double-check your xml path in the project: `Resources/xml/file_paths.xml`
- After a build, check the *build artifacts* for the file in `obj/Debug/android/res/xml`

If the resource file is not in the build artifacts the likely cause is the build action is wrong

- Check that the *build action* on the file is set to **`AndroidResource`**